# Creating EditText with button

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-view

I must create EditText with button inside and assign functions which will run after pressing the button. Then I would like to make it reusable - somehow add it as an element to my Activity. I was wondering about extending EditTextView and adding button and creating functions inside of it.
Any suggestions/ tutorials?

Comment: Post what all have you done.

Comment: Hi, You want like password visible or hide kind of, or done to do some operation..?

Comment: Hi check my answer, I gave one example to put some icon inside edit text and make it clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:completionHint="yourhint"
                android:dropDownHeight="match_parent"
                android:hint="From"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@id/image"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>


      </LinearLayout>
```

And set OnClicklistener to the button in your OnCreate method like this:

```
Button image = (Button) findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
//handle your on click event here
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to Create Custom View Components

Below links has sample and will solve your problems

https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want some icon or button inside edit text you can achieve like this,

> Note: In this just I am using setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds,
>   So if you want to change the icon position you can achieve that using
>   setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds in setIcon.

Create some CustomEditText like this,

```
public class MKEditText extends AppCompatEditText {

    public interface IconClickListener {
        public void onClick();
    }

    private IconClickListener mIconClickListener;

    private static final String TAG = MKEditText.class.getSimpleName();

    private final int EXTRA_TOUCH_AREA = 50;
    private Drawable mDrawable;
    private boolean touchDown;

    public MKEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public MKEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MKEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void showRightIcon() {
        mDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp);

        setIcon();
    }

    public void setIconClickListener(IconClickListener iconClickListener) {
        mIconClickListener = iconClickListener;
    }

    private void setIcon() {
        Drawable[] drawables = getCompoundDrawables();

        setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawables[0], drawables[1], mDrawable, drawables[3]);

        setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
        setSelection(getText().length());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final int right = getRight();
        final int drawableSize = getCompoundPaddingRight();
        final int x = (int) event.getX();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (x + EXTRA_TOUCH_AREA >= right - drawableSize && x <= right + EXTRA_TOUCH_AREA) {
                    touchDown = true;
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (x + EXTRA_TOUCH_AREA >= right - drawableSize && x <= right + EXTRA_TOUCH_AREA && touchDown) {
                    touchDown = false;
                    if (mIconClickListener != null) {
                        mIconClickListener.onClick();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                touchDown = false;
                break;

        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

> If you want to change the touch area you can change the
>   **EXTRA_TOUCH_AREA** values default I gave as 50.

And for Enable the button and click listener you can call from your Activity or Fragment like this,

```
MKEditText mkEditText = (MKEditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
mkEditText.showRightIcon();
mkEditText.setIconClickListener(new MKEditText.IconClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
              // You can do action here. ex you can start activity here like this
               startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SampleActivity.class), 1);
            }
        });
```

Comment: how can I call function startActivityForResult? I've got an error here. shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale doesn't work either.

Comment: You want to call startActivityForResult inside onClick..?

Comment: Then you need some permission in that activity.

Comment: no, inside my custom function. I would like to get edittext with button and getting to other activity after pressing the button and checking on-time-permissions. Your answer is ok but I wonder where should I place these functions? For example create custom edittext class and then add functionalities to it?

Comment: you can do inside onClick()

Comment: Is it possible to start an activity after clicking button? `startActivityForResult` doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148502/discussion-between-muthukrishnan-rajendran-and-codddeer123).

Answer (score 0):

You can extend LinearLayout or RelativeLayout and add both Button and EditText in the constructor. However, you need to use a getter method to get the EditText or Button. Here is an example. I haven't tested it, but it should give you an idea. Just remember that, if you want to use xml attributes of Button or EditText, you should define them in attr.xml and then get them with TypedArray. Since the object is a LinearLayout, you cannot use EditText or Button attributes without defining them in attr.xml.

```
public class CustomEditText extends LinearLayout {

private AppCompatButton mButton;
private AppCompatEditText mEditText;

public CustomEditText(Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);
}

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);

    /** Get Attributes **/

    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomEditText);

    int lines = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.CustomEditText_android_lines, 1);
    int gravity = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.CustomEditText_android_gravity, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    int inputType = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.CustomEditText_android_inputType, InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    int imeOptions = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.CustomEditText_android_imeOptions, EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    String hint = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.CustomEditText_hint);

    typedArray.recycle();

    /** Construct Button **/

    mButton = new AppCompatButton(context);
    addView(mButton);

    /** Construct EditText **/

    mEditText = new AppCompatEditText(context);
    mEditText.setGravity(gravity);
    mEditText.setHint(hint);
    mEditText.setImeOptions(imeOptions | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
    mEditText.setInputType(inputType | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    if (!((inputType & InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE) == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE
            && lines == 1)) mEditText.setLines(lines);
    addView(mEditText);
}

public AppCompatEditText getEditText() {
    return mEditText;
}

public AppCompatButton getButton() {
    return mButton;
}
}
```

Comment: @codddeer123 see the example and let me know if anything is not clear.